# Adding <param> element to <object>

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What i'm trying to do is add a new `<param>` tag inside an `<object>` that is already loaded to a page. This is because i'm trying to stop the flash element of the object from coming in front of all my drop-down menus (add wmode=opaque). I'm trying the following:

```
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
    var i =0;
    for (i=0; i<elements.length ; i++){ //check all the objects in the page
        var children = elements[i].childNodes;
        var j = 0;
        for (j=0 ; j<children.length; j++){
            var paramname = children[j].name;
            var paramvalue = children[j].value;
            if (paramname=="movie" && paramvalue.indexOf("blahblah") != -1) { //this is the object i'm interested in
                var newparam = document.createElement('param');
                newparam.setAttribute('name', 'wmode');
                newparam.setAttribute('value', 'opaque');
                elements[i].appendchild(newparam); //this line causes the error
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

running the script gives me this error: `"Object doesn't support property or method 'appendchild'" (Line: 22)`
What am i doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried with big `C`.

```
elements[i].appendChild(newparam);
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas! Struggling so many hours i didn't even notice. Even rewriting the code i kept writing it with a small `c`...